# typedef, structure and type compatibiliy

Tags: c, struct

If I have these two structs:

```
struct
{
   int x;
} A;

struct
{
   int x;
} B;
```

then making `A = B;` results in a compilation error because the two anonymous structs are not compatible.

However if I do:

```
typedef struct
{
   int x;
} S;

S A;

S B;
```

`A = B;` is a legal assignment because they are compatible.

But why? With `typedef` I understand that the compiler makes this when meet `S A` and `S B`:

```
struct { int x; } A;
struct { int x; } B;
```

so `A` and `B` should not be compatible...

Comment: "With typedef I understand" -- you understand wrong; typedef is an alias for the type, it's not a macro. It's the same type in both cases.

Comment: With your earlier approach if you do: `struct A first; struct A second` then compiler won't throw an error for `first = second`. You must understand that `struct A` and `struct B` are different even though their bodies are exactly same.

Comment: @NikhilVidhani, you can't do struct A first; struct A second; because the struct is anonymous but you can do: struct { int x; }first, second;

Comment: @xdevel2000 I meant to say this: `struct A {int x}; struct A first, second; first = second;` but as it turns out, I misinterpreted the question. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each anonymous struct declaration is a distinct type; this is why you get a type mismatch when trying to assign one to the other.

A typedef, however, declares an alias (i.e. a new name for something that already exists) for a type (it does not create a new type).

A typedef is also **not** a simple text replacement, like a preprocessor macro. Your statement

> I understand that the compiler make this when meet `S A` and `S B`:
>
> ```
> struct { int x; } A;
> struct { int x; } B;
> ```

is where your understanding is wrong.

When you use the type alias `S`, as in

```
S A;
S B;
```

the types of both objects `A` and `B` are the same by definition and assigning one to the other is possible.

Comment: +1 for easily the most apropos answer. C99 6.7.8(5) has an example that is *very* close to the OP's sample, btw.

Comment: @Jens, please, can you explain better this "the types of both objects A and B are the same by definition" and what the compiler make, at low level, if typedef is not a simple text replacement?

Comment: @xdevel2000 `typedef` declares an alias for a type. It's just a different name. That means that with `S A;` you don't define the type `A`, but declare a variable of type `S`. `A` and `B` are therefore variables of type `S`, not different types. That's why you can do the assignment `A = B`.

Comment: @xdevel2000 Think of typedefs as creating a non-anonymous (aka tagged) struct, i.e. something like `struct tag1 { int x;}` and then the compiler, upon seeing `S A; S B;` treats it as `struct tag1 A; struct tag1 B;`.

Comment: @xdevel2000 6.7.8 is the section, (5) is the paragraph number. Its there.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you're wrong! 6.7.8(5) is into 2011 C specification not in C99 specification.

Comment: @xdevel2000 then someone has some 'splaining to do with my doc-server, because they have that spec labeled C99. Now that I look at the header, its indeed ISO/IEC 9899:201x n1548. Indeed you are correct. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

This is because C treats every untagged `struct` as a new kind of `struct`, regardless of the memory layout. However, `typedef struct { } name;` cannot be used if you want to use the `struct` in a linked list. You'll need to stick with defining a structure tag in this case, and `typedef` the tagged `struct` instead.

Comment: `typedef struct` _can_ and should be used, you merely have to combine it with a struct tag to give you an incomplete type: `typedef struct node { ... ; struct node* next; } node_t;`

Comment: @Lundin But that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: But you said it has to be typedef:ed afterwards, which isn't true. You can mix the typedef with the declaration as I showed.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But by afterwards, I mean that you're `typedef`ing `struct node`, and not `struct {}`. In your mixed declaration, the `typedef` effectively works on `struct node`. You could even put `typedef struct node node_t;` before the declaration of `struct node` and still get the same effect.

Comment: No... when written together, you typedef the whole struct, regardless of the presence of the struct tag, to be of type `node_t`. The struct tag is only there to declare an incomplete type, which allows you to declare a pointer to the struct before the whole definition of the struct is complete. That has nothing to do with the typedef as such. When you typedef the struct on a separate line before the struct definition, you also create an incomplete type. If you do it after the struct definition however, the struct already has a definition and you merely typedef that definition to another name.

Comment: Ah, now I see that there is a difference between the two ways when I look at it line by line. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: If one wishes to refer to types via typedef, a somewhat cleaner way to handle a linked list would be `typedef linkNode struct linkNodeTag; struct LinkNodeTag {linkNode next; ... }`.  That would allow the type to be specified the same way within the struct as outside.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct DistanceInMeter /* Anonymous 1 */
{
  int x; /* distance */
};

struct VolumeInCC /* Anonymous 2 */
{
  int x; /* volume */
};

struct DistanceInMeter A;
struct VolumeInCC B;
...
A = B; /* Something is wrong here */
```

Equating different type doesn't always make sense and thus is not allowed.

```
typedef struct DistanceInMeter /* Anonymous 1 */
{
  int x; /* distance */
} Dist_t;
Dist_t C, D;
...
C = D; /* Alright, makes sense */
```

Comment: Your struct are not anonymous because they have tags.

Comment: @xdevel2000 I have used tags to convey my idea(How struct containing same member types with same layout are different). Word anonymous is used to show analogy with OP. My `DistanceInMeter` is `Anonymous 1` of OP.